# Cannot get JSON echo from PHP to $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  array_push($json_result,
  array('crewID'=>$row[0],
  'FName'=>$row[1],
  'LName'=>$row[2],
  'smBook'=>$row[3],
  'contactNo'=>$row[4],
  'email'=>$row[5],
  'address'=>$row[6],
  'birthday'=>$row[7],
  'emergencyCN'=>$row[8],
  'emergencyPerson'=>$row[9],
  'loyaltyCN'=>$row[10]));
}

echo json_encode(array($json_result),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
function displayGuestData(guestID) {
  $.ajax({
    url:"functions/f_get_guests_json.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{guestID:guestID},
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(response) {
      alert(response.FName);
    }
  });
}
```

Now my problem is I'm getting an undefined error when I alert any of the JSON data like `FName`. What could be the problem? I'm new with JSON in jQuery. I even have this code in my PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
```

EDIT:

This is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "crewID": "4",
    "FName": "Abc Abc",
    "LName": "Abc",
    "smBook": "ABC123",
    "contactNo": "12312312",
    "email": "asdasd@yahoo.com",
    "address": "56 Sasdasd Asds",
    "birthday": "1995-06-11",
    "emergencyCN": "12312312",
    "emergencyPerson": "asdasdasd",
    "loyaltyCN": "ABC123"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please also add at least a snippet of the output of your php script?

Comment: this is your array structure: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [crewID] => 
                    [FName] => 
                    [LName] => 
                    [smBook] => 
                    [contactNo] => 
                    [email] => 
                    [address] => 
                    [birthday] => 
                    [emergencyCN] => 
                    [emergencyPerson] => 
                    [loyaltyCN] => 
                )

        )

)
`
use `response[0][0].FName` to get array item

Comment: Add console.log(response); in success function of ajax will help you to know the value returned from server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here;

```
success: function(response){
    alert(response.FName);
}
```

You are returning, as far as I can tell, an array which contains your results.
So perhaps you should attempt changing the above to the following;

```
success: function(response){
    alert(response[0].FName);
}
```

This accesses the first result in the array, and proceeds to access then alert the contents of it's `FName` attribute.

Using `console.log(response)` would be a good way to view the full object your dealing with, and therefore work out how to use it.

---

## Updated

Since you have provided the output json, it appears you have an array containing an array of your results.

You'll be able to see this clearly if you use `console.log` but you need `response[0][0].FName` to puncture through your two arrays.

Comment: when I use alert(response[0].FName) the response was "undefined"

Comment: Did you try `console.log(response)`?

Comment: I think it will be well worth your time to learn about `console.log`. It makes issues like this very easy to debug.